# ssh doesnt work with public ip address but just locally

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

I've a SSH server on my raspberry pi running on ubuntu. For a while I've used normally, then for some reason it stopped working with the public ip and when try to connect get this error:

```
ssh: connect to host: Network is unreachable
```

what happened? i tried uninstalling `openssh-server` and reinstalling it but it didn't work

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to indicate if you are behind a CGNAT.

Comment: i couldn't figure out if the CGNAT is enabled or not. the MAP-T instead is activated if can help. btw on my desktop where another openssh server is activated, ssh works fine. Only with raspberry pi I've this problem.